# Why does iOS UIPasteboard return nil string value after copying?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement an iOS Clipboard Listener using Objective C which runs in the background listening for copies anywhere outside the app.

The logic I am using is implemented in https://github.com/vitoziv/VIClipboardListener, the main points are:

1. Add an observer for the `UIPasteboardChangedNotification` event

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(pasteboardChanged:)
                                            name:UIPasteboardChangedNotification
                                          object:nil];
   ```
2. Start a background task which will watch for changes to the `UIPasteboard`

   ```
   UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
   _bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
       [app endBackgroundTask:_bgTask];
       _bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
       [self checkPasteBoardCount];

       [app endBackgroundTask:_bgTask];
       _bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   });
   ```
3. Inside the `checkPasteBoardCount` method, watch for changes to the `UIPasteboard` by checking the `pasteboard.changeCount` every second and comparing to the last value

   ```
   UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
   NSInteger changeCount = pasteboard.changeCount;
   NSInteger bgTaskTime = BACKGROUND_TIME;
   while (bgTaskTime >= 0) {
       //NSLog(@"app in background, left %i second.",bgTaskTime);
       if (changeCount != pasteboard.changeCount) {
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIPasteboardChangedNotification object:nil];
           changeCount = pasteboard.changeCount;
       }
       [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:SLEEP_TIME];
       bgTaskTime -= SLEEP_TIME;
   }
   ```

This should cause our observer's `pasteboardChanged` method to be called every time there is a change in the `UIPasteboard` contents. That change should be accessible using the `UIPasteboard.string` etc. methods.

Running this on an emulator gives perfect results, the `pasteboardChanged` method gets called on every copy from any app while the app runs in the background, and the contents of the `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]` always contain the copied content.

However, when running this on a real device, despite the fact that the observer is indeed called on every copy, the content of the `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string` property is almost always `nil`. On some rare occasions (maybe when quickly reopening the app after copying from outside) the actual value was there, but it seems random.

Are there any context-related rules to accessing the Pasteboard data on a real device, such as only being able to read content created from within the same app? Or could there be differences in thread management between the emulator and a real device?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. I was only able to test on the one device so far, will try another one to confirm the behavior.

Comment: Not directly related but you should not be posting the UIPasteboardChangedNotification yourself.

Comment: That seemed incorrect to me as well. Does the system dispatch this event so that I could just subscribe to it? Do you happen to have an example or link that I can check out on this point? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the system posts that notification. Read the documentation for `UIPasteboard changeCount`.

Comment: I tried removing the line where I post the notification, but now the selector never gets fired. I'll try on a real device, maybe it's because of the emulator? Anyway, it seems like I'm not the only one with this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868751/nsnotificationcenter-pasteboardchangednotification-not-firing